# Javascript and css files getting 404 error on my jsp page after using @PathVariable

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, web.xml

For some reason when I changed the mapping of my jsp in my spring controller to use a path variable none of the javascript or the css files will load. I can't find any other examples on the net of this happening. I'm guessing it's some mapping issue in my web.xml but I don' really know.

Here is my controller code..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "common/taskSummary/{taskInstanceId}.do",  method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView taskSummary(
        @PathVariable("taskInstanceId") int taskInstanceId) {
    // Get user from Spring security
    User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("taskSummary");
    modelAndView.addObject("username", user.getUsername());
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Here is my web.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping> 

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml  
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>           
<resource-ref>
    <description>ArcFlashMap DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/AFM_DB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>    
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoadResourcesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ie.premiumpower.services.reports.common.LoadResourcesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

And here is the errors I'm getting on firebugs console...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I had been mapping my css and js files using href="../css/style.css"
but this needed to be changed to href="../../css/style.css". Adding the extra "../".